# How Can I display username after login in Asp.net.Core Mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How can I display username after user login, I use temp date, but username did not show, this is my code.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can follow some tutorials about asp.net on the Internet

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: Where did you set the tempdata, I can't see it from the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the login is successful, you can set a cookie (if not exists of course). Checkout [here](http://www.programmerguide.net/2014/12/creating-cookie-in-aspnet-mvc-action.html#:%7E:text=We%20can%20create%20Cookie%20and,ASP.NET%20MVC%20Action%20method.)